# In-app transaction completed, then I got disconnected and could not verify the receipt on my server side. How should I handle this situation?

Tags: android

I'm looking for information regarding the following situation.
When I complete an in-app transcription procedure in googleplay in my app, I obtain a receipt. Then I need to verify that receipt on my server-side. But what happens if just before that, I lose my network connection. I need to save that (or those) receipts and process them later. Is there an efficient way or work flow I should use to handle this kind of situation?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Google's in-app purchasing API.